# If index is larger than length

Tags: php

I'm trying to get one character from a string. I can use an index which is larger than `strlen` as in the example below: (index: 9)

```
$string = "abcd";
echo substr($string, 9, 1);
//necessary result: b
//str: abcd abcd ab <-- b
//idx: 0123 4567 89 <-- 9
```

It can not be used `substr` probably, OK. But Im not sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the modulo of the index with the string length, and that will give you the effect of wrapping the string:

```
$string = "abcd";
echo substr($string, 9 % strlen($string), 1);
```

Output:

```
b
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FspYS)

Comment: woow,  smart solution :) 1+

Comment: @alexso thanks. btw out of curiosity I benchmarked that solution against `$string[9 % strlen($string)]` and `substr` was 33% faster.